# How to return the value without the bracket in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
  $da = User::where('email',$email)
            ->get()
            ->lists('id');
```

This is on my controller, and the result return like this `[1,2,3,4]`. But i want to return without the bracket [ ] .So is that possible to do that or must return the value with the [ ] ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return a string rather than an array?

Comment: Yaya, but how to do that?

Comment: Because i just return one value and pass it to my database. I

Comment: You can convert an array to a string with `implode()`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user PHP's `implode($glue,$array)` function as follow:

```
$da = User::where('email',$email)
        ->get()
        ->lists('id');

return implode(', ', $da);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp